# Is it possible to access fields from managed-package objects?

Tags: visualforce, managed-package

Is there a way to pass data from Salesforce to a VisualForce page in a managed package and vice-versa (get data from the VF page in the managed package over to SF)?

Context:

My Sandbox is using the managed app Shipmate. We currently have two Shipping Preferences (warehouses).
The task I need to accomplish is to enable the manual selection of warehouses from a drop-down directly on the Opportunity Page Layout in SF, and then pass that info over to Shipmate so it populates the correct return address information in the wizard based on the selected warehouse.

This is the link to documentation, but there is no mention of how to do that or if it is possible: https://docs.zenkraft.com/ups.

Comment: You can directly manipulate managed package data. Only part you are missing is since you can not access Apex logic, your managed package may behave differently (now or in future when you have a different version). I would suggest to contact managed package publisher and ask for a help.

Answer (score 2):

Although your question is not clear enough, in general the answer is divided into 2:

1. If you want to access the managed package data - meaning using SOQL or formulas to query managed package objects - this can be done easily with stating the namespace prefix of the package before each object.
2. If you want to access a page or other component (that use code) of the managed package - usually this cannot be done.

If you want a more acurate answer, please state what exactly you want to achieve - which object is within the managed package? which fields? what is this wizard (from managed package?) etc.